# Personalizar el panel work with cuando fue invocado con workwithpanel.panel.detail.insert(&BC)

Tags: genexus

En una aplicación Nativa Mobile.
GX18

Desde un panel con el pattern work with invoco a otro en modo insert precargando la variable de tipo BC con algunos valores predeterminados.
Otros valores quiero que el usuario los pueda ingresar interactivamente antes de salvar.
Pero estoy intentando personalizar el formulario que le voy a mostrar al usuario en base a uno de los valores que paso en la variable &BC

ejemplo simplificado:

//Panel de invocación

```
&BC.Tipo = 1
&BC.UsuarioId = 123
WorkWithTrn.Trn.Detail.Insert(&BC)
```

//Panel de destino
Quisiera poder hacer algo así.

```
If Tipo = 1
  Control.visible = True
Else
  Control.visible = False
Endif
```

Se que (Tipo=1) está llegando porque si ejecuto el save del panel, la información se guarda correctamente.

Pero no estoy logrando que entre en el If para actualizar el formulario.

Probé en el Event Load , if &BC.Tipo = 1.....

Entiendo que al tratarse de un evento de cliente puede haber una lógica de carga del formulario que no estoy sabiendo en qué momento invocar la actualización del mismo.

Desde ya les agradezo sus sugerencias.